# nginx: http to https redirect doesn't work

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to do http to https redirect for sickbeard using nginx 1.6.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 and it doesn't work.

Here's the config for sickbeard:

```
upstream sickbeard  {
  server localhost:8081;
}

server {
  listen *:80;         
  server_name sb.mydomain.com;
  server_tokens off;
  root /nowhere; 
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name sb.mydomain.com;
  server_tokens off;

  ssl on;
  ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-MD5;
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;
  ssl_certificate      server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  server.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://sickbeard;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

So `https://sb.mydomain.com/home` works, `http://sb.mydomain.com/home` doesn't (it times out).

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work. I had to add the following line in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1    sb.mydomain.com    sb
```